# form select on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have data look like this

```
id    rel    word

1     A     word A
2     B     word B
3     B     word C
```

to get the data my controller look like this :

```
public function get_new()
{
return View::make('form.new')
    ->with('datas', Data::all());
}
```

and my View will look like this :

```
<select>
@foreach($datas as $data)
<option value="{{ $data->id }}" rel="{{ $data->rel }}">{{ $data->word }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

How i can get that data with Form::select ?

If we use `Form::select` we can call that with `Data::lists('word','id')` and pass to the view.
but if i use this i just can get 2 data that is id and word.

how can i get all data that is `id, rel and word with Form::select`. Please help me.

Comment: What you're doing already makes sense.  `Form::select()` is designed to give you a very simple output.  If you find yourself doing this a lot you could always write your own function to produce this output.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, so, maybe i must create the helper function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4s `FormBuilder` and `HtmlBuilder` aren't going to produce *everything* for *everyone*. Taylor himself has said that he wants to keep it lean and simple. The solution you have now is probably the best way you could go about it (using a simple loop).

`Form::select` isn't capable of automatically populating other attributes of the option element. If you want this functionality you're going to either have to make yourself a custom macro or write your own form generator.

Probably not the answer you're after but that pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i will try to make like your suggest

Answer (score 0):

Just want to update the solution...

```
<select name="name" id="name">
@foreach($datas as $data)
<option value="{{ $data->id }}" {{ (Input::old('name', 0) === $data->id ? ' selected="selected"' : '') }} rel="{{ $data->rel }}">{{ $data->word }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

This will give old input on selected option